# Excel VBA: Scraping HTML data behind script

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have this HTML, and I'm trying scrape the values behind `data-v-88f004c6` after "Compra:" and after "Venta:"

```html
<div class="info-tc" data-v-88f004c6>
  <span data-v-88f004c6>Tipo de cambio del dólar hoy en Perú</span>   
  <span data-v-88f004c6>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle i-help" data-v-88f004c6></i>
  </span>
  <span data-v-88f004c6>Compra: 
    <strong data-v-88f004c6></strong>
  </span>
  <span data-v-88f004c6>Venta: 
    <strong data-v-88f004c6></strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

When I bring up the developer tools from Chrome I can see that the values appear like this (3.199 and 3.237):

```html
<div class="info-tc" data-v-88f004c6="">
  <span data-v-88f004c6="">Tipo de cambio del dólar hoy en Perú</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span data-v-88f004c6="">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle i-help" data-v-88f004c6=""></i>&nbsp;
  </span>
  <span data-v-88f004c6="">Compra:&nbsp;
    <strong data-v-88f004c6="">3.199</strong>
  </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span data-v-88f004c6="">Venta:&nbsp;
    <strong data-v-88f004c6="">3.237</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

However when I scrape the values using Excel I get symbols like this for the prices.

> Tipo de cambio del dÃ³lar hoy en PerÃºÂ Â Â  Â Compra:Â  Â Â  Venta:Â

I'm using a code like this to scrape the [web](https://kambista.com/):

```
    Set GetRawHTML = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", urlWebSite, False
        .send
        GetRawHTML = .responseText
    End With
    kambistafx = GetRawHTML.body.innerHTML
    fxprice = kambistafx .getElementsByClassName("info-tc").Item(0).innerText
```

What should I do to scrape those values?

Comment: Are you trying to get the table containing those value you have mentioned in your post? Have you tried using IE?

Comment: IE is another method for scraping data from Excel? I haven't tried it. But it's weird that function doesn't work, it's the first time I have a problem with it.

Comment: It's the first time for you to encounter such trouble because you never scraped any dynamically generated items. However, be it `winhttp`, `xmlhttp`, or `serverxmlhttp`, they can't handle javascript heavy items. So, the best choice for you in this case is to choose any browser simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/)

CSS selectors

```
#__layout span:nth-child(2) +*") 'compra
#__layout span:nth-child(3) +*") 'venta
```

These are contracted versions of full selectors which were:

```
#__layout > div > main > section.banner > div.central-section > div.col.paddingTop2 > section > div > span:nth-child(2) > strong
#__layout > div > main > section.banner > div.central-section > div.col.paddingTop2 > section > div > span:nth-child(3) > strong
```

---

Example CSS query:

[image: CSS query]

Source page values

[image: Source]

---

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfoSel()
    Dim d As WebDriver, keys As New keys
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://kambista.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get URL
          Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("#__layout span:nth-child(2) +*").Text 'compra
          Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("#__layout span:nth-child(3) +*").Text  'venta
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Note:

After installing Selenium basic and opening excel you need to add a reference via  VBE > Tools > References > Selenium type library

Comment: Hi, Did you try this please? I went to the effort of answering it for you.

Comment: Yes, but not on my work terminal. I can't install selenium on that computer.